# Excepciones al orden alfabético en los siglos XVI y XVII

Tags: historia, diccionarios

Buscando definiciones de *jarro* y *jarra* en diccionarios antiguos me encuentro con una curiosidad:

1. En los diccionarios de Nebrija (1495) y Alcalá (1505) aparece *jarro* antes que *jarrero*.
2. En el diccionario de Oudin (1609) aparece *jarro* antes que *jarrillo*.
3. En el diccionario de Rosal (1611) aparece *jarro* antes que *jarrete*.
4. En el diccionario de Covarrubias (1611) aparece *jarro*, luego *jarrear* y luego *jarra*.

En otros diccionarios de la época, en cambio, sí que parece respetarse un orden alfabético escrupuloso, como el de Minsheu de 1617 y otros. El *Autoridades* del siglo XVIII también sigue un orden alfabético estricto.

¿Qué orden seguían pues los diccionarios mencionados de los siglos XVI y XVII? ¿Tal vez se ponía primero el sustantivo principal y luego las palabras derivadas? ¿Se le daba preferencia al masculino si aparecían las variantes masculinas y femeninas de una palabra en la obra? ¿Había alguna regla al respecto por la época o se dejaba todo al criterio del autor?

Comment: @walen eso es lo que pasa cuando redactas la pregunta a 15 minutos de tener que salir corriendo a recoger al peque de la guarde. :-)

Comment: Parece que la palabra base, *jarro*, aparece primero, y luego vienen los demas miembros de la familia.