# ¿Están las palabras de este documento ordenadas según algún criterio conocido?

Tags: historia, alfabeto

[Este documento](http://www.memoriachilena.gob.cl/archivos2/pdfs/MC0059621.pdf), publicado en Chile en 1897, contiene una lista de plantas medicinales. El documento está ordenado por grupos de palabras, desde la A a la Z (usando, sorprendentemente, el listado actual, esto es, sin CH y LL, que no parece ser el que era aprobado [en aquella época](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18914/cu%C3%A1l-ha-sido-la-evoluci%C3%B3n-del-abecedario-espa%C3%B1ol-a-lo-largo-del-tiempo/21079)). Sin embargo, mirando dentro de los grupos de letras, es evidente que el orden no es el que se usa en los diccionarios. Por ejemplo, "Almendro" viene después de "Aromo".

¿Tiene el orden observado alguna lógica? No logro captarla. ¿Quizas algún método que sea propio de esa época, que ya no se use hoy en día?

Comment: Relacionado: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/30503/excepciones-al-orden-alfabético-en-los-siglos-xvi-y-xvii

Comment: No veo patrón alguno.  Para algunas letras parece estar ordenado más que para otras.

Answer (score 2):

No parece que haya ningún método consistente en la elaboración de la lista, excepto la agrupación por letra inicial. Hay trechos más o menos largos de lista ordenada alfabéticamente y otros donde el orden parece aleatorio. Los trechos en sí tampoco están ordenados, digamos, por las primeras dos o tres letras comunes a las palabras de cada trecho. En algún caso parece como si a la lista correspondiente a una letra dada, ya ordenada correctamente, se le hubieran añadido elementos sueltos (desordenados) a posteriori. En otros hay grupos de no más de tres palabras bien ordenadas, pero mezclados sin orden con otros grupos similares.

Quizá la idea de esta lista nunca fue el orden alfabético de diccionario. Quizá se consideró que ordenar por la inicial sería suficiente para que el lector encontrase rápidamente la palabra buscada. Esto no es muy difícil, porque incluso las iniciales con mayor cantidad de palabras (como la A o la C) no tienen tantas que no pueda recorrerse la lista con la vista en unos pocos segundos. Desconozco si en otros libros similares de la época se utilizaban listas o índices creados con este criterio.